# How to use join to get last 15 days unsold products using mysql.

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table( items & transactions ).
1. **items** which will have current stock. **transactions** will have sold items data. **"item_code"** column is common in both tables.
I want to use a join query and get all the stocks past 15 days which are not sold even once. 
This can easily be achieved using nested select but i wanted to used joins to optimize it.
The problem i am facing while using join is that below code can only show me proper data if at least one transaction record for every item is in table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT items.code from items LEFT JOIN transactions ON 
    items.code = transactions.itemCode
    WHERE
    transactions.transDate NOT BETWEEN (DATE(NOW())- INTERVAL 15 DAY) AND CURRENT_DATE
    ORDER by transactions.transDate DESC
```

Any help and suggestions will be admired and supported!

Comment: You might get the correct result here if you move the condition from `WHERE` into the `ON` as in `ON items.code = transactions.itemCode AND transactions.transDate NOT....`  When posting a SQL question it is always most helpful to include a small sample of rows from the tables together with a sample of what the expected query output should be from that sample rowset.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT items.item_code as item_code
FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions
    ON items.item_code = transactions.item_code
    AND transactions.transDate >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 15 DAY 
    AND transactions.transDate < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
WHERE transactions.item_code IS NULL
```

For example today is `16 June 2018 14:45`, I assume that you want to find items that are not being sold from `01 June 2018 00:00:00` to `16 June 2018 23:59:59`

The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` will preserve the row in `items` table having no match in `transactions` table, then filter unmatched out with `WHERE`

Comment: this is the extracted query from your statement... "SELECT transactions.transDate,items.code as item_code
FROM items LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions
    ON items.code = transactions.itemCode
    AND transactions.transDate >= (DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 7 DAY )
    AND transactions.transDate < (DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY )". Unfortunately this was not working and it returned all the items_code from items as i expected and i had to add "transactions.transDate" col to check which returned the matched date and rest were null. But its is not the code neither was the result.

Comment: Sorry forgot the `WHERE transactions.item_code IS NULL` condition. See updated answer